# REST API custom endpoint without authentication for POST method?

Tags: rest-api

I need a custom WordPress REST API endpoint with POST method to receive some data from external domains. The issue is requests are not authenticated & I can't apply authentication methods. There is no security issue at all because the data is in a specific format & validated and sanitized in the callback function. Also, data is never saved in DB in the same format. That means, now the endpoint must be public.

Before WordPress 5.5, the below code snippet is working without any issue.

```
function register_rest_route_check_update() {
    register_rest_route(
        REST_API_NAMESPACE, REST_API_ROUTE,
        array(
            'methods' => 'POST',
            'callback' => array( 'callback_function'),
        )
    );
}
```

But after WordPress 5.5 update, I got the below message.

```
Notice: register_rest_route was called incorrectly. The REST API route definition for "abcd" is missing the required permission_callback argument. For REST API routes that are intended to be public, use __return_true as the permission callback.
```

So I have added permission callback as suggested. Now my code look like below one.

```
function register_rest_route_check_update() {
    register_rest_route(
        REST_API_NAMESPACE, REST_API_ROUTE,
        array(
            'methods' => 'POST',
            'callback' => array( 'callback_function'),
            'permission_callback' => '__return_true',
        )
    );
}
```

Now when I submit data to custom API endpoint, I got below message.

```
{"code":"rest_not_logged_in","message":"You are not currently logged in.","data":{"status":401}}
```

I believe that this is an authentication error. But I can't use any authentication method here. So can I make that custom API endpoint as pure public without any authentication?

Also, I have a custom key with me on the submitted data. Can I use that custom key for any authentication?

Note: My intention in using REST API is to make communication between multiple WordPress sites in multiple domains using `wp_safe_remote_post` & `wp_safe_remote_get` request. That means some data is submitted into custom REST API endpoint etc.

UPDATE: Consider that the WordPress with custom API endpoint is a server & in client-side, I'm using `wp_safe_remote_post()` function.

```
wp_safe_remote_post( $target_url, array('body' => $request_data) )
```

UPDATE: If I return a false value to `rest_authentication_errors` filter, there is no further authentication error. But I believe that disabling authentication for all API endpoints may become a security issue later.

```
add_filter('rest_authentication_errors', '__return_false');
```

---

**Update: The issue was automatically resolved without any changes in the code or file.**

I have attached the code snippet that will be useful for someone else. Public API that accepts POST requests is always vulnerable.

**In server-side**

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'register_rest_route_abcd');

function register_rest_route_abcd() {
    register_rest_route(
        'myapi/v1', 'myroute',
        array(
            'methods' => 'POST,GET',
            'callback' => 'my_callback_function',
            'permission_callback' => '__return_true',
        )
    );
}

function my_callback_function($request){
    
    //Do logic here
    
    // Prepare response
    $response = array();
    $response['status'] = true;
    $response['message'] = 'done';
    
    return $response;
}
```

**In clint side**

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'ed45r_my_action', 5 );
function ed45r_my_action(){
    
        $target_url = 'http://localhost/server-sys/wp-json/myapi/v1/myroute';
    
        $data = array(
            'key_1' => 'value_1',
            'key_2' => 'value_2',
        );
        
        $request = wp_safe_remote_get( $target_url, array('body' => $data) );
        
        if(is_wp_error($request) || wp_remote_retrieve_response_code($request) != 200){
            
            // Know the errror
            
        } else {
            
            $response = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request );
            $response = json_decode($response, true);
            
            // Process the response
            
        }
    
}
```

In my case, the action is not a `template_redirect`. It is a form submission.

Comment: Are you very sure you accessed the correct endpoint, e.g. `example.com/wp-json/my-plugin/v1/foo` ? Or that the notice was indeed for your custom endpoint? What's the value of the `REST_API_NAMESPACE` and `REST_API_ROUTE`?

Comment: Yes. My endpoint is the correct one & before WordPress 5.5 update, it is working without any issue. After the update, my code gives the permission_callback error & then after I got this authentication error. Even if I return a false value to `rest_authentication_errors`, the error goes away & my custom end point works without authentication error. But I believe that disabling authentication for all end point may be a security issue later. I will update my question with the filter detail.

Comment: Can you show how are you accessing the endpoint or more of your code, both the client/request and server/response sides? You could also try deactivating plugins and activate them back one at a time until the issue is fixed.

Comment: Dear @SallyCJ , I think, I have done some mistakes. As per your suggestion, when I do a wp_safe_remote_post on template redirect, there is no further error. But in my real case, it is a form in client file. When I'm submitting the whole form data & there is nonce in the form data. I think, that makes this issues.

Comment: Yes, I believe so, and keep in mind that if your request include a nonce, then use a [valid one](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/).

Comment: @SallyCJ, The issue is not related to nonce. The issue was automatically resolved! I don't know what happens. I haven't made any changes to the files or code. Thank you for your help. I have updated my question with my code. If you get time, request you to review it.

Comment: Your code is good, except the version string (`v1`) for the endpoint should be part of the namespace (see the [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/#namespacing)), which is the first parameter for `register_rest_route()`, e.g. `register_rest_route( 'myapi/v1', 'myroute', ... )`.